# Is it 'safe' to open port 80 for web hosting?

Tags: ip, port-security

I am new to this whole section of hosting services. I looked up online on how to self host my website, and all the websites told me to set up the software (Apache server) and open port 80 to make my IP public, that's where this question came to me. Would it be safe to open port 80 and host a website that is available for the public? I would be using my home/personal computer, and that getting hacked would give me a tough time.

Thank you all in advance for the help!

Comment: Questions about home networking are specifically off-topic here, but you can ask those questions on [su].

Comment: Sorry about that, there are so many categories that it is hard not to get confused on what to post XD

Answer (score 1):

Opening any service to the internet carries a risk. How big that risk is depends on a number of factors including.

1. What privilages is the server running under? A server running as root (or your operating system's equivilent) is obviously a higher risk than one running as a dedicated low-privilage user but note that privilage escalation bugs do happen.
2. What is the server doing? A webserver than only supports static content is much lower risk than one running a complex webapp.

Comment: So technically if I run the server in a virtual environment, it is safer than running it on the real computer? Thanks!

Comment: No, it isn't. This is a question for the security stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

You should run the Webserver in an isolated vitual machine withput an access to the rest of your network. You can do this with VLAN for example.